# "Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component." when trying to redirect from root layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, expo-router

Simple case, I want my app to operate mainly on a tab navigation so I did files hierachy as on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXY2v.png) and write that code:

app/_layout.js

```
const RootLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="(tabs)"
        options={{
          headerTitle: "",
          headerShadowVisible: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

app/index.js

```
export default function Root() {
  return <Redirect href="/home" />;
}
```

app/(tabs)/_layout.js

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="stock"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Stock",
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="news"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "News",
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

Because of this Redirect I have an error as in the title.

I tired to put for example Link instead of Redirect and everything works fine but I don't want user to click anything, just tab navigation from the start

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? You can use the [initialRouteName](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#initialroutename) prop to start on the home screen

Comment: @Abe when I put initialRouteName as a prop to Stack in app/_layout then how should app/index.js look like? Empty or should I delete it? If I simply add props to Stack and delete redirect (function Root is empty) it simply showing blank index page

Comment: I tried to use unstable_settings but still not working. If I put "(tabs)" in initialRouteName there I get blank index page with back button leading to tab navigation pages but still it is not what I want